# Avoid generic constraints duplication

Tags: typescript, generics, alias

I am trying to make alias for generic class constraint to avoid duplication.
So change this code:

```
class Base<T extends Flyable>{} 
class Sub1<T extends Flyable> extends Base<T>{} 
class Sub2<T extends Flyable> extends Base<T>{}
```

To something like this:

```
type FlyableObj = T extends Flyable

class Base<FlyableObj as T>{} 
class Sub1<FlyableObj as T> extends Base<T>{}
class Sub2<FlyableObj as T> extends Base<T>{}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No, this is not possible and I advise you just stick with your original code as it's shorter and makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

No, it is not possible.

Personally, I prefer your original code over the proposal. Might be verbose, but its easy to understand